# No callee has been set

Tags: ink, unit-tests

I write some test for ink! smart contract, my code has these three lines:

```
    // Set the contract as callee and Bob as caller.
    let _contract = ink_env::account_id::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>();
    ink_env::test::set_callee::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(_contract);
    ink_env::test::set_caller::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(_accounts.alice);
```

But still I get `no callee has been set` error, what I do wrongly?

Comment: try to set up a dev environment and single step your code until you see what variable does not hold its expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not ideal solution, but working.

```
let _accounts = ink_env::test::default_accounts::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>();
let contract_addr: AccountId = AccountId::from([0xFF as u8; 32]);
set_callee::<DefaultEnvironment>(contract_addr);
```